# How does Apache order the evaluation of Alias and ScriptAlias?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-alias

Under `mod_alias`, how does Apache order `Alias` and `ScriptAlias` directives with respect to each other?

The [mod_alias docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) say

> The `ScriptAlias` directive has the same behavior as the `Alias` directive, except that in addition it marks the target directory as containing CGI scripts...

but it's not clear to me that this is meant to imply that `ScriptAlias` directives are mixed into the same "pool" as `Alias` directives when Apache determines evaluation order.

For a specific example, I ask because I've encountered the configuration

```
Alias       /pub         "/var/www/service/files"
ScriptAlias /pub         "/var/www/service/bin/view"
```

and if the `ScriptAlias` is evaluated just as if it were any other Alias, then no request will never match the second line.

Are `ScriptAlias` directives evaluated before, after, or at the same time as `Alias` directives?

Comment: You would probably have to read the source code to be sure. This particular scenario is so senseless that the configuration should probably just quietly be fixed and move on.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What would you say is senseless about it?

Comment: For a URL beginning with `/pub` there is no way for a computer to tell whether the `Alias` or the `ScriptAlias` should be used. The behavior is undefined, and also unpredictable.